# How can I get the language name in it's respective language by locale?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

I want to display a list of languages to choose from. For example, if I supposed Japanese and English then the drop down would show two options like so:

```
日本語
English
```

Answer (score 1):

in your config/locale_settings.yml add

```
available:
  ja: "日本の"
  en: "English"
```

then in dropdown,

```
      <%= f.select :locale, available_language_options %>
```

where available_language_options defined as

```
  def available_language_options
    options = []
    AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES.each do |locale, language|
      options << [language, locale]
    end
    options.sort_by { |o| o[0] }
  end
```